# Does a $\text{PDE}$ solution have to be continuous?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity

An answer to the title question will be perfectly acceptable to me! But for more detail behind my motivation:

I'm given the problem (Shearer and Levy, Problem $1.7$), "Determine why the initial boundary problem
$$\begin{align*}
u_t - 4u_x &= 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 < x, 0 < t, \\
u(x,0) &= 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 < x, \\
u(0,t) &= te^{-t}, \ \ \ 0 < t, 
\end{align*}$$
does not have a solution."

My thought: I can come up with $u(x,t) = (\frac{x}{4} + t) \cdot e^{-(\frac{x}{4} + t)}$, and I have verified that this equation satisfies the relationship $u_t - 4u_x = 0$ and it is also continuous with the boundary condition $u(0,t) = te^{-t}$. But this "solution" would result in a jump discontinuity along the $x-\text{axis},$ where the initial condition is defined. Similarly, the equation $u(x,t) = 0$ would satisfy $u_t - 4u_x = 0$, and would be continuous with the initial condition, but would have a jump discontinuity at the $t\text{-axis}.$ So, there is no way to get a solution that is continuous within the first quadrant of the $x-t$ plane *and also* continuous along the appropriate parts of the $x-$ and $t-\text{axes}.$ BUT, that explanation assumes that having a "solution" that is discontinuous is not allowed!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is "solution" defined in the book? If yes, then follow the definition. They hopefully would have been careful to state continuity of the solution up to the boundary. Physically, what would the point of an initial condition if you could instantaneously jump away from it?

Comment: Sadly, not, at least not in a satisfying way: "A solution of a PDE...is a real-valued function u satisfying the equation. Often this means that u is as differentiable as the PDE requires, and the PDE is satisfied at each point of the domain of u. However, it can be appropriate or even necessary to consider a more general notion of solution, in which u is not required to have all the derivatives appearing in the equation." So if differentiable, then continuous, but then he walks back the differentiability requirement. The comment about "the point" of an initial condition is helpful though!

Comment: oh well. Then I think you can take this exercise as a clarification on the definition. I should add; jumping is a little weird, jumping to an arbitrary point is weirder still. If you allowed one of them to be discontinuous, why not both, and then literally any solution of $u_t - 4u_x= 0$ (and there are many) would be a solution for the boundary value problem, which is certainly odd

Comment: It seems that $u(x,0) = (x/4)e^{-x/4}\neq 0$ for $x>0$, so your $u$ doesn't satisfy the required boundary conditions, does it?

Comment: @MPW, yes I think that is the part that is confusing me. I'm not sure if my $u$ is supposed to be defined on the open first quadrant, and then the initial/boundary conditions define the solution along the boundary...or if my $u$ should be defined on the closed first quadrant, and also agree with the initial/boundary conditions.

Comment: Ah! That part IS defined in the book. The book says that the solution u(x,t) should be defined for 0 less than or equal to x, and 0 less than or equal to t. So u(x,t) should be defined along the boundaries as well, and then u(x,t) should AGREE with the boundary conditions. It's not possible to come up with u(x,t) that agrees with the boundary conditions. Thank you both for the breadcrumb trail. VERY helpful.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The solution has the form $\ds{\on{f}\pars{x + 4t}}$. Then,
$\ds{0 = \on{u}\pars{x,0} = \on{f}\pars{x} \implies
\bbx{0 = t\expo{-t}\,\,\, \forall t >0}\ \color{red}{\Huge !!!}}$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Is it possible that you could explain why this doesn't lead to a contradiction for the PDE u_t + 4u_x = 0, with the same boundary conditions? It would seem to me that then 0 = u(x,0) = f(x) again...so why does that NOT lead to the same contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Consulting *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans, there is a more rigorous definition of the solution to a partial differential equation (page 7):

> We say that a given problem for a partial differential equation is *well-posed* if
>
> 1. the problem in fact has a solution,
> 2. this solution is unique, and
> 3. the solution depends continuously on the data given in the problem.

He then observes

> Now clearly it would be desirable to "solve" PDE in such a way that
> (1)-(3) hold. But notice we still have not carefully defined what is
> meant by a "solution". Should we ask, for example, that a "solution"
> *u* must be real analytic or at least infinitely differentiable? This might be desirable, but perhaps we are asking too much. Maybe it would
> be wiser to require a solution of a PDE of order *k* to be at least
> *k* times continuously differentiable. Then at least all the derivatives which appear in the statement of the PDE will exist and be
> continuous, although certain higher derivatives will not exist. Let us
> informally call a solution with this much smoothness a *classical*
> solution of the PDE.

This definition is sufficient to answer the question above: Should the solution to a PDE be continuous? Well, a *classical* solution to a PDE should not only be continuous throughout its domain, but it should also be at least $k$ times continuously differentiable, where $k$ is the order of the PDE.

However, Evans continues by asking of the classical solution:

> But can we achieve this? The answer is that certain specific partial
> differential equations can be solved the classical sense. But many
> others, if not most others, cannot...we may be forced by the structure
> of the particular equation to abandon the search for smooth, classical
> solutions. We must instead, while still hoping to achieve the
> well-posedness conditions (1)-(3), investigate a wider class of
> candidate for solutions.

So, here's how all of this relates to the specific homework problem: The question's author gives two solutions that are not only continuous everywhere, not only $k$ times differentiable everywhere, but are smooth everywhere. There is no need, in this problem, to pursue alternative definitions of "solution"; the classical definition works just fine. In this problem, the issue isn't that the "solutions" $u(x,t)$ posed by the asker are discontinuous. The issue is that any equation $u$ that satisfies the relationship $u_t - 4u_x = 0$ will fail to simultaneously satisfy the required boundary conditions.

.

---

Note: Since I originally asked the question, I happen to also know that "the asker" of the question was confused. He thought that the relationship $u_t - 4u_x = 0$ is used to define the solution everywhere on the first quadrant of the $x$-$t$ plane except along the positive $x$- and $t$-axes, i.e. everywhere *but* the boundary. And then the boundary conditions are used to define the solution on these axes. If that were the case, the resulting function would be piecewise and *would* be discontinuous at the boundary. But that's the wrong mental model for how these boundary condition problems work. Rather, the relationship $u_t - 4u_x = 0$ is used to define a set of solutions across *the entire* first quadrant, including the positive axes, i.e. including along the boundary. Then the boundary conditions are used to select *the one* solution from this set that agrees with the specified boundary conditions, if such a solution exists. In this case, there are plenty of solutions that are defined across the first quadrant and that are continuous and even smooth. But among these candidates, there is no solution that agrees with the boundary conditions, so there is no solution to the problem.